# Опосредовать — лексическое значение слова

Tags: лексика, семантика

Каково лексическое значение глагола *опосредовать* в предложении:

***Гражданский процесс опосредует всю судебную деятельность*** (из вузовского учебника по гражданскому праву)?

Я плохо понимаю данное слово именно в этом предложении. Опосредовать — значит выражать опосредованным образом (через посредство чего-то другого) либо служить передаточным звеном, посредником в выражении чего-либо.

Что  получается: гражданский процесс есть выразитель всей судебной деятельности? Судебная деятельность воплощается в гражданском процессе? Выражается посредством гражданского процесса?

Comment: Гражданское процесс? Такое согласование?

Answer (score 1):

Получается так. Если гражданский процесс представляет собой **процессуальную форму защиты гражданских прав**, возложенную законом на суды, то гражданский процесс — это и есть деятельность суда (гражданское судопроизводство) и иных специально уполномоченных законом органов по защите гражданских прав.

При этом мы должны иметь в виду, что судебная власть вообще (правосудие) в Российской Федерации осуществляется посредством **конституционного, гражданского, административного и уголовного судопроизводства** (ст. 118 Конституции РФ).

Таким образом, фраза Вашего учебника касается только **гражданского судопроизводства**, не уголовного и не конституционного. Речь идёт о том, что  **гражданское судопроизводство осуществляется через гражданский процесс**.

```
 Что получается: гражданский процесс есть выразитель 
 всей судебной деятельности?
```

Не совсем, скорее не выразитель деятельности, а выразитель **основ** судебного производства. Просто гражданское процессуальное право — историческая основа других процессуальных отраслей. *Арбитражный процесс, судебный административный процесс, третейское разбирательство, конституционное правосудие строятся на тех же началах,* что и гражданский процесс, воспринимают генетически из него основные принципы и институты. Близки по своей юридической природе к гражданскому судопроизводству также нотариальное и исполнительное производства, которые имеют многие общие принципы и начала.

Comment: Выходит, мое предположение в общем корреспондирует с тем, что написали вы. 

А опосредует Б, то есть сущность Б выражается посредством А.